# select records according to the difference between records R

Tags: r, select, conditional-statements, records, difference

I hope someone could suggest me something for this "problem", because I really don't know how to proceed...
Well, my data are like this

```
data<-data.frame(site=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),time=c(100,180,245,5,55,130,70,120,160))
```

where time is in minute. 
I want to select only the records, for each site, for which the difference is more than 60, so the output should be Like this:

```
out<-data[c(1:4,6,7,9),]
```

What I have tried so far. Well,to get the difference I use this:

```
difference<-stack(tapply(data$time,data$site,diff))
```

but then, no idea how to pick up those records which satisfied my condition...
If there is already a similar question, although I've searched for a while,  I apologize for this.
To make things clear, as probably the definition of difference was not so unambiguous, I need to select all the records (for each site) which are separated at least by 60 minutes, so not only those that are strictly subsequent in time.
Specifically,

```
> out
site time
1    A  100#included because difference between 2 and 1 is>60
2    A  180#included because difference between 3 and 2 is>60
3    A  245#included because separated by 6o minutes before record#2
4    B    5#included because difference between 6 and 4 is>60
6    B  130#included because separated by 6o minutes before record#4
7    C   70#included because difference between 9 and 7 is>60
9    C  160#included because separated by 60 minutes before record#7
```

May be to solve the "problem", it could be useful to consider the results of the difference, something like this:

```
> difference
values ind
1     80   A#include record 1 and 2
2     65   A#include record 2 and 3
3     50   B#include only record 4
4     75   B#include record 6 because there are(50+75)>60 m from r#4
5     50   C#include only record 7
6     40   C#include record 9 because there are (50+40)>60 m from r#7
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "difference is more than 60"? Do you mean the diff with the previous value of the same site? In your vector `out`, you are including row 5 which has a time value of 55 with previous row having value 5. Are rows with the same site always together?

Comment: @ALiX, sorry my out was partly wrong.My sincere excuses...

Comment: Please update your question with the details you have given here in the comments.

Comment: @Henrik, I did. Sorry!

Comment: @stefano, Sorry I don't follow your logic. You write "select all the records (for each site) which are separated at least by 60 minutes". Why then isn't record 5 included? The difference between 5 and 6 is 75. Please add explicit calculations for some of the rows where you also explain in words why a particular row should be included or not. Thanks.

Comment: @Henrik, so the record 5 is not included because the difference between 5 (55) and 4 (5) is less than 60 minutes, therefore I consider only the first record (4). I am going to add the explanations requested in the question. Thank you!

Comment: Then the rule is _not_ "select all the records (for each site) which are separated at least by 60 minutes". Again, please be _explicit_ about the criteria for inclusion. I really wish to help, but first I need to understand the underlying logic...

Comment: Sorry, I hope the explanations for each out-rows will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data[ave(data$time, data$site, FUN = function(x){c(61, diff(x)) > 60}) == 1, ]

#   site time
# 1    A  100
# 2    A  180
# 3    A  245
# 4    B    5
# 6    B  130
# 7    C   70
```

**Edit** following updated question:

```
keep <- as.logical(ave(data$time, data$site, FUN = function(x){
  c(TRUE, cumsum(diff(x)) > 60)
}))

data[keep, ]

#   site time
# 1    A  100
# 2    A  180
# 3    A  245
# 4    B    5
# 6    B  130
# 7    C   70
# 9    C  160
```

Comment: While very close, this misses the last row requested by the output.

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks for your comment. I aimed for the output posted by OP in the comment `out <- data[c(1,2,3,4,6,7), ]`. I see now that it doesn't agree with the update in the question...

Comment: The inclusion of the last row actually makes the problem quite a bit more complex. It's no longer a simple `diff` operation, but (conceptually to me anyway) requires several passes to identify rows which become `>60` after the removal of other rows.

Comment: @thelatemail, yes you are definitely right. Probably my previous explanation was not so clear. I want to select any records for which there is at least 60 minutes, and of course this should be done for each site separately.

Comment: Hi @Henrik, thank you so much! I sincerely appreciate your help!

Comment: @stefano, No problem, glad to help! When I finally understood what you were looking for... ;) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Calculate the differences
data$diff <- unlist(by(data$time, data$site,function(x)c(NA,diff(x))))
#subset data
data[is.na(data$diff) | data$diff > 60,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `plyr`:

```
ddply(dat,.(site),function(x)x[c(TRUE , diff(x$time) >60),])
```